# How to center align stacking elements, and how to stretch one horizontally?

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-layout

Good morning. I'm trying to create [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3b0zP.jpg) screen. Two problems with that:

1) I can't stretch the green horizontal line to the entire width. This is my code, more or less:

```
Scaffold(
  Stack(
    Center(
      Column(
      ...
      ),
    ),
    Align(
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      child: Image(
        image: AssetImage('assets/load_line.png'),
        fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
      ),
    ),
```

And [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I8tnf.png) is what my code is giving me. Seems like there is a padding or margin somewhere, but I can't find it.

2) As you can see in my first screenshot, I need the logo and the horizontal line to center one on top of the other, but they obviously miss align. I thought using a single image, but I'm afraid the stretching would ruin it. What can I do to achieve this result?

Thanks, everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this way.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    backgroundColor: Colors.green,
    appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Title")),
    body: Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        Align(child: Image.asset("assets/images/profile.jpg")),
        Align(child: Container(height: 1, color: Colors.black12)),
        Align(
          alignment: Alignment(0.0, 0.2),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: <Widget>[
              Text("Your first text here!"),
              Text("Your second text here"),
              Text("Your third text here!"),
            ],
          ),
        )
      ],
    ),
  );
}
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: Worked like a charm, I didn't knew you could use `Align()` in that way. Could you give a look at my other [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55578619/how-to-position-elements-inside-a-listview)? Thanks @CopsOnRoad

Comment: Yes, I am taking a look there. Thanks for accepting it. Please share your screenshot there.