# How to position elements inside a ListView?

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-layout

Good morning. I made [this screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LbsGp.jpg) and it works like a charm on high resolutions. Problem is, I want to support lower resolutions like Nexus 4 (768x1280).

So when I run this on an emulator (Nexus 4 size) and I touch the input fields, the keyboard either: blocks the inputs, or moves the two buttons at the bottom and overlaps them on something else.

So, to solve it I wrapped the entire layout on a ListView(), but now the bottom buttons, which are wrapped on a Row(), just won't stay at the bottom.

This is my code without the ListView and working on high res, but not on low:

```
return Form(
  Stack(
    Center(
      Column(
        ...
      ),
    ),
    Align(
      alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
      child: Row(
        ...
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v8o02.png) is how it looks with resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false
And [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I0Cj6.png) is how it looks with the value set to true

Thanks, everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to use SingleChildScrollView ?

It is a widget for making the page able to resize the height and as well scrolling , for the listview thats not what is the listview for , you should add listview when you get an unknown amount of data,

We don't normally use it to just adjust the view.

---

ok so i edited the code as in here and i can scroll normally after the keyboard pop up and the view is good and i can click on the button normally try it.

```
  Widget formWidget(){
    return new Scaffold(
      // appBar: AppBar(
      //   // Here we take the value from the MyHomePage object that was created by
      //   // the App.build method, and use it to set our appbar title.
      //   title: Text(widget.title),
      // ),
      body:Column( 
          children: <Widget> [ 
          Expanded(
       child:SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Form(

          child: 
          // Stack(
          //   children: <Widget>[
              // Center(
                // child: SingleChildScrollView(
                  // child: 
                  Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,

                    children: [
                      Padding(
                        padding: (MediaQuery.of(context).size.height) > 600
                            ? const EdgeInsets.only(top: 0.0)
                            : const EdgeInsets.only(top: 30.0),
                        child: Image(
                          image: AssetImage('assets/favIcon.png'),
                          width: 88.0,
                          height: 88.0,
                        ),
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 28.0, 0, 12.0),
                        child: Text(
                          'Delegados',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontFamily: 'Archia',
                            fontSize: 32.0,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Text(
                        'Introduce tus datos de acceso aquí.',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Color(0xff83868F),
                          fontFamily: 'Brutal',
                          fontSize: 14.0,
                        ),
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding:
                        const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(16.0, 26.0, 16.0, 12.0),
                        child: TextFormField(
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                            labelText: 'Correo',
                            filled: true,
                            fillColor: Color(0xffF0F1F5),
                            border: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
                              borderSide: BorderSide(
                                width: 0,
                                style: BorderStyle.none,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontFamily: 'Brutal',
                            color: Color(0xff1A1B1F),
                          ),
                           controller: TextEditingController() ,

                            textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                        ),
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(16.0, 0, 16.0, 12.0),
                        child: TextFormField(
                          keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                            labelText: 'Contraseña',
                            filled: true,
                            fillColor: Color(0xffF0F1F5),
                            suffixIcon: Icon(Icons.remove_red_eye),
                            border: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
                              borderSide: BorderSide(
                                width: 0,
                                style: BorderStyle.none,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontFamily: 'Brutal',
                            color: Color(0xff1A1B1F),
                          ),
                           controller: TextEditingController() ,
                           //focusNode:FocusNode(),

                          obscureText: true,
                        ),
                      ),
                      Align(
                        alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 26.0),
                          child: CupertinoButton(
                            onPressed: () {},
                            child: Text(
                              'Olvidé mi Contraseña',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                color: Color(0xff565A66),
                                fontFamily: 'Brutal',
                                fontSize: 14.0,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(16.0, 0, 16.0, 0),
                        child: ButtonTheme(
                          minWidth: double.infinity,
                          child: InkWell(
                            // onTap: state is! LoginLoading
                            //     ? _onLoginButtonPressed
                            //     : null,
                            child: Container(
                              height: 48.0,
                              width: 500.0,
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                color: Color(0xff00CC36),
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
                              ),
                              child: Align(
                                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                                  child: Container(
                                    child: 
                                    // state is LoginLoading
                                    //     ? CircularProgressIndicator():
                                         Text(
                                      'INGRESAR AHORA    ›',
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                        color: Colors.white,
                                        fontFamily: 'Brutal',
                                        fontSize: 14.0,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  )),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),

                    ],
                  ),
                // ),
              )
              ,
              // aqui va <<<<<<<<<<<<
            // ],
          // ),
             )  
       ),
       Align(
                        alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,

                        child: Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            CupertinoButton(
                              onPressed: () {},
                              child: Text(
                                '¿No tienes cuenta?',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Color(0xff83868F),
                                  fontFamily: 'Brutal',
                                  fontSize: 14.0,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            InkWell(
                              onTap: null,
                              child: Container(
                                height: 32.0,
                                width: 112.0,
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6.0),
                                  border: Border.all(
                                    color: Color(0xffD7D9E0),
                                    width: 1.0,
                                  ),
                                ),
                                child: Align(
                                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                                  child: Text(
                                    'CONTACTANOS',
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        color: Color(0xff565A66),
                                        fontFamily: 'Brutal',
                                        fontSize: 11.0),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),

       ]

       )

       ,

    // )
    );
  }
```

Comment: The problem with that is that wrapping the elements inside ListView() or SingleChildScrollView() makes the Row() positioned at the bottom of the screen, move up next to the green button, you can see it [here](https://i.imgur.com/iivHmBD.png).

Comment: as you are doing this --alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter-- which forces it to be aligned bottomcenter

Comment: did you try this  new Expanded()? so use expanded with SingleChildScrollView()

Comment: Since SingleChildScrollView() has infinite space, Expanded will make it expand indefinitely, and result in a blank screen.

Comment: [This](https://pastebin.com/Cm3xa64Q) is the code without an Expanded() or SingleChildScrollView() on it. Maybe I'm positioning it wrong, thanks for your help.

Comment: alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter why you use this and at the same time you want dynamic alignment?

Comment: I need the scrolling because I need the UI to look good on high and low resolutions.

Comment: [This](https://i.imgur.com/zxdWuf0.png) is an example of what I want. On the left is what I get with SingleChildScrollView() (I'm running your code), and to the left if what I want, and what I see without SCSV().

Comment: edited it again check it and uncomment the ontap :)

Comment: With a little tweaking to position it closer to the center, that worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In your `Scaffold` can you try this.

```
Scaffold(
  resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
  ...
);
```

Comment: This gets me the same [result](https://i.imgur.com/d2EwS0Z.png) as with resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false. I've added two screenshots to my post.

Answer (score 0):

I position two elements in the center and bottom of the screen by this code.

```
body: Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: Center(
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  SizedBox(
                      height: 80,
                      width: 80,
                      child:
                          Image(image: AssetImage("assets/images/logo.png"))),
                  SizedBox(height: 10),
                  Text(
                    "Tings App",
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 36),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 10),
                  TextFormField(
                    controller: _emailController,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                        isDense: true,
                        labelText: 'Email/phone'),
                    validator: (value) {
                      if (value.isEmpty) {
                        return 'Please enter a valid email';
                      }
                      return null;
                    },
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
            child: Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                children: <Widget>[
                  _isLoading
                      ? CircularProgressIndicator()
                      : SizedBox(
                          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.7,
                          height: 60.0,
                          child: ElevatedButton(
                            style: ButtonStyle(
                              shape: MaterialStateProperty.all<
                                  RoundedRectangleBorder>(
                                RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100.0),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            child: Text(
                              "SignIn",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w800,
                                  fontSize: 18),
                            ),
                            onPressed: () {
                              _login(context);
                            },
                          ),
                        ),
                  SizedBox(height: 16),
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      Text(
                        "Don't have account?",
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(width: 6),
                      TextButton(
                        onPressed: () {
                          Navigator.push(
                              context, SlideRightRoute(page: Signup()));
                        },
                        child: Text("SignUp"),
                      ),
                    ],
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
```